# Postgres 9.5 deadlock with many updates on a table + many "select for update" on another table

Tags: postgresql, update, deadlock, deadlock-graph

I have two tables: "machines" and "magictools". "magictools" refers to "machines" with a foreign key.

I face a deadlock problem while executing many of these requests:

```
//this will produce an "AccessExclusiveLock" of type "tuple" on machines
SELECT FROM * machines FOR UPDATE where id = :id;
//this will produce a "RowExclusiveLock" on magictools and a "RowShareLock" on machines
UPDATE magictools SET collections = "large-json" where id = :id
```

As far I understood running many of these request produces deadlocks. Maybe it's only the updates who are performing this, I don't know.
How should I avoid the deadlocks in this case?

I have many indexes on these tables, maybe I have too many indexes?

Below is the report of pg_activity when the problem happened. I do not understand the different modes and lock types, and, just, what happens here?
Is it possible that just an update without any transaction causes a deadlock?

[deadlock trace link](https://pastebin.com/EVCDynvD)

Comment: [Postgres 9.5 reaches EOL in February 11, 2021](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider upgrading to a current version. (May also help with your issue.)

Comment: You've edited your post to show a WHERE clause, but your pastebin link still doesn't show a WHERE clause.

Comment: The requests in paste in are just flags, I considered they are not needed to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no deterministic `ORDER BY` in:

```
SELECT FROM * machines FOR UPDATE;
```

So multiple transactions might try to obtain row locks in different (arbitrary) order and interlock.

Also, why would you lock the whole table `machines` for a single update in `magictools`? If it's indeed a single `UPDATE` on `magictools` per transaction, there is no need to lock rows `machines` manually at all. Just drop the command. (If there are multiple, then your question is lacking.)

If there is a good reason to lock many or all rows in `machines`, either do it in deterministic order, like:

```
SELECT FROM * machines ORDER BY id FOR UPDATE;
```

Or lock the whole table instead, that's also cheaper:

```
LOCK TABLE machines IN SHARE MODE;
```

`SHARE MODE` is enough for the FK case you have. There is even an [example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-lock.html#id-1.9.3.155.8) suggesting as much.

Locking the table also disallows `INSERT`, of course, unlike the row level locks in your example.

Comment: Thank you. My apologies, the "select * from machines" query has a where on the PK. I edited my question to reflect the reality.

Comment: @Slim: Please edit some more to clarify. There are multiple "id" floating around. Please clarify what's what, where each transaction starts and ends and whether the given commands are complete. Table definition showing relevant columns with all constraints also help.

Comment: thank for your time. I realized my question was too complicated and I've created another one here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281846/is-it-possible-than-two-simple-updates-on-same-table-interlocks

Comment: I think your answer is useful so I prefer to let this one as is.